# Why can't I run a code twice in jupyter python for the input function?

Tags: python, input

Why can't I run a code twice in jupyter python for the input function?

Example

```
print(input("what is your name?"))
```

Also it won't let me use the input function afterwards throughout the notebook. No output is shown, just an `[*]`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to restart the kernel. You will find the Kernel option on the toolbar. After this choose the Restart and clear output. It worked on my notebook.

[Here you can find a picture to find the Kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE3lj.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "*" means that the code is running. Nothing else will run until this is over.
In your case, "input" waits for a user input. So until you enter something, you won't be able to run anything.